# Why does a Rust macro re-exported from another crate work unless there's a dependency conflict

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-tracing

I'm writing a Rust crate for internal company use that wraps the excellent Tokio `tracing` crate, with a bit of additional functionality.  Not only do I re-export the macros in `tracing`, but I also add a few of my own that internally invoke the `tracing` macros.  My goal is to enable all of our other internal crates to depend only on my wrapper crate, without having to pull in `tracing` dependencies explicitly in each crate.

This works really well, until I ran into an issue today that took me a few hours to isolate.  I've made a minimal example to show the behavior [here](https://github.com/anelson/rust-macro-reexport-problem).

In this example, I have a workspace with two crates: `my-logger-crate` which wraps `tracing` and exposes a macro `print_trace!`, and a binary crate `my-binary-crate` which has a dependency on `my-logger-crate`, and invokes the macro inside the `main` function.

The `Cargo.toml` for `my-logger-crate` is very simple; the only thing I added to the auto-generated skeleton is a `tracing` dependency:

```
[package]
name = "my-logger-crate"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["Adam Nelson <anelson@users.noreply.github.com>"]
edition = "2018"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
tracing = "0.1.12"
```

This is the `my-logger-crate` macro:

```rust
/// Re-export everything in the `tracing` crate
pub use ::tracing::*;

/// A version of the `trace!` macro that sets a special target
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! print_trace {
    ($($arg:tt)*) => (
        // Invoke the `trace!` macro which is defined in the `tracing` crate but which has been
        // re-exported from this crate, so that downstream callers don't have to take an explicit
        // dependency on `tracing`
        $crate::trace!(target: "console", $($arg)*)
    )
}
```

This is used by `my-binary-crate`, whose `Cargo.toml` is also simple:

```
[package]
name = "my-binary-crate"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["Adam Nelson <anelson@users.noreply.github.com>"]
edition = "2018"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
my-logger-crate = { path = "../my-logger-crate" }

# If the following line is uncommented, then the call to `print_trace!` in `main()` fails to compile.
# tower = "0.3"
```

And here's the `main()` function in `my-binary-crate`:

```rust
fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");

    // Log a trace event with the logging system
    my_logger_crate::print_trace!("this is a trace message from print_trace!");
}
```

If `my-binary-crate` doesn't have any conflicting dependencies, this compiles and runs fine.

But take a look at what happens if we have a dependency on `tower` in the [`my-binary-crate/Cargo.toml`](https://github.com/anelson/rust-macro-reexport-problem/blob/master/my-binary-crate/Cargo.toml) file:

```
[package]
name = "my-binary-crate"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["Adam Nelson <anelson@users.noreply.github.com>"]
edition = "2018"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
my-logger-crate = { path = "../my-logger-crate" }

# If the following line is uncommented, then the call to `print_trace!` in `main()` fails to compile.
tower = "0.3"
```

Here's what happens:

```
Compiling my-binary-crate v0.1.0 (/home/cornelius/scrap/e2780c4bd3dfa24758fcfd93e225b100/my-binary-crate)
error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared type or module `tracing`
 --> my-binary-crate/src/main.rs:5:5
  |
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ use of undeclared type or module `tracing`
  |
  = note: this error originates in a macro outside of the current crate (in Nightly builds, run with -Z external-macro-backtrace for more info)
```

The `print_trace!` macro is expanding out to the `tracing::trace!` macro, which then expands to `tracing::event!`, and then expands to the code to log an event, which includes calls to `tracing::...`.  All of this works fine before I add that `tower` dependency, so clearly the compiler is able to resolve `tracing::...` properly, even though `my-binary-crate` doesn't have a direct dependency on `tracing` itself.

I suspect this is related to a dependency conflict.  `tower` pulls in a long dependency tree, including `tower-buffer`, which itself has a dependency on `tracing = "0.1.2"`.

My understanding of how Cargo resolves this seeming conflict is that it would use `tracing` version `0.1.12`, since my logging crate explicitly depends on version `=0.1.12`, and `tower-buffer` specifies `0.1.2`, which is equivalent to `^0.1.2`.  But I don't understand why adding this additional dependency tree breaks the use of my macro.

For the moment I've worked around it by adding explicit dependencies on `tracing` in all of the downstream crates that use my logging crate, but that's far from ideal.

I ran with macro tracing enabled:

```
$ RUSTFLAGS="-Z macro-backtrace" cargo +nightly test
   Compiling my-binary-crate v0.1.0 (/home/cornelius/scrap/e2780c4bd3dfa24758fcfd93e225b100/my-binary-crate)
error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared type or module `tracing`
   --> <::tracing::macros::__mk_format_args macros>:78:17
    |
1   |    /  (@ { $ (,) * $ ($ out : expr), * $ (,) * }, $ fmt : expr, fields : $ (,) *) =>
2   |    |  { format_args ! ($ fmt, $ ($ out), *) } ;
3   |    |  (@ { $ (,) * $ ($ out : expr), * }, $ fmt : expr, fields : $ ($ k : ident) . +
4   |    |   = ? $ val : expr $ (,) *) =>
...      |
78  |    |          (@ { }, tracing :: __mk_format_string ! ($ ($ kv) *), fields : $
    |    |                  ^^^^^^^ use of undeclared type or module `tracing`
79  |    |           ($ kv) *)
80  |    |      }
81  |    |  } ;
... [a lot of macro expansions snipped]
```

Not surprisingly, the error is an attempt to call `tracing::__mk_format_string!`, which fails because there is no such crate `tracing` referenced by `my-binary-crate`.  The strange thing is that in order to get to this error, several other macros in `tracing` had to be evaluated.  Perhaps this is a bug in `tracing`, and it should be `$crate::__mk_format_string!`.  However I still don't understand why this works until I add a `tower` dependency on `my-binary-crate`.